# "Correct me if I'm wrong"

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I had always had the impression that when people say, "correct me if I'm wrong", their underlying meaning is not to ask for correction but to stress that, "I'm 100% sure of what I'm saying", especially during heated debates.

Is that so?  Please "correct me if I'm wrong", hahaha.

(there will be a follow up question if it is indeed so)

Comment: Personally, I've never come across the rhetorical meaning of this phrase. It's always been - "I think this is right, but if you disagree, correct me."

Comment: Generally, from my experience, it simply means, "I'm confident that I'm correct, but not entirely certain, so correct me if I am wrong". I do not believe it infers a connotation of being "100% certain". More like "99% certain".

Answer (score 61, accepted):

It's used both ways – it can indeed be an expression of confidence, but it can also be a genuine request for clarification. And even in the former case, you can usually assume that the speaker is in fact reasonably open to being corrected. (Though maybe not in a "heated debate"!")

Comment: "I think I'm right, but accept that I might be wrong."

Comment: But also, "I'm so certain I'm right I don't mind giving you the opportunity to correct me"

Comment: To underline what is said above, if said in a sarcastic tone of voice, then it means "I REALLY don't think I'm wrong", but if said 'evenly' then it means that the speaker isn't entirely sure of himself, and should be taken at face value. How they will react to being corrected is a seperate question.

Comment: @MikeBrockington *Correct me if I'm wrong*, but doesn't a sarcastic tone flip the meaning of *anything* that's being said?

Comment: This is a type of expression that I tend to avoid, even as a native speaker, because it can be misinterpreted quite easily depending on who is listening.  *"For your information..."* is another, for example.  They are overly sensitive to variations in the listener's state of mind and can be taken the wrong way even when the speaker uses them correctly.

Comment: @FooBar  Presumably I didn't empasise enough, that sarcasm is very commonly used with this phrase. The original question was specific to one phrase, so I wasn't really trying to address sarcasm in general.

Comment: @J... I find in text format, those phrases can be pretty sticky, but verbally it's pretty easy to get the intention of the phrase for me.  For your information is one that I don't even have much trouble with in text format.  It comes up all the time in emails and very rarely does it give off anything besides a neutral tone to me.

Comment: @JMac "_FYI_, you are wrong"

Comment: @some_name Depending on context, even that doesn't seem that rude.  The only reason it would make sense to me to include FYI there would be if it was orthogonal to the conversation anyways, so someone pointing out that _for my own information_ I had incorrect information is not necessarily a bad thing.  "By the way, you're wrong" or just "You're wrong" already can be very rude just due to the terseness.  Adding in, or replacing BTW with FYI, doesn't really make things worse.

Comment: This is often a way to temper saying "you are wrong", by making the correction into a quasi-question or a point of discussion, instead of just a direct contradiction. "Correct me if I am wrong but I think the sky is actually blue, not green." or even "Actually, excuse me, correct me if I'm wrong but I think the sky may actually be considered to be more blue instead of green." vs "The sky is blue, not green." It does come across as condescending if you overdo it...

Comment: It can also be a challenge to those present to dare to correct the speaker

Answer (score 20):

I hear "correct me if I'm wrong, [name]" quite often in my office environment. It is used when someone is answering the question that they were asked while at the same time acknowledging that someone else in the conversation may have better knowledge to offer.

They might also say "keep me honest, [name]" for the same effect of inviting someone to chime in with additional details or corrections.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, "correct me if I am wrong" is mostly heard from people who've come to a particular conclusion from their experience of how earlier instances of how the same situation has played out. 
There is a reasonable expectation that they're right unless you have a valid clarification/explanation for changing their opinion.

Used sarcastically, it could be just a "humbler" way of asserting their stand and expecting you not have a factual opposition to it.